# How to not get contents of child elements within HtmlUnit?

Tags: screen-scraping, htmlunit

I have the following:

```
<th>
Q4/10
<br>
<span> Nov 30, 2010 </span>
</th>
```

and I'd like to get `Q4/10` but not the date that follows.  I'm not sure how to do it within HtmlUnit. I know I can split both elements by spaces and then take everything before the first space, but I'm looking for something based on the tags themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that the text you want comes *before* any sub elements, you can just grab its first child, which will contain your text and some whitespace:

```
HtmlTableHeaderCell th = ...
System.err.println( th.getFirstChild().toString().trim() ) ;
```

The more general solution would be to loop through the children of `th` looking for text nodes, and ignoring sub elements.

Comment: Thanks Rodney. I didn't know that. I thought the child elements were only what was below what I was seeking.  I'll check it out.  Thanks.